# ¿Cómo acceder a un vector obtenido después de usa sentencia fetch en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, fetch

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
  listById (name: String): any[] {
    let elementElectrico: Array<any> = [];
    function getName(nameElect) {
    const elemetElec = [];
    const featureRequest2 = new WFS().writeGetFeature({
      srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureTypes: ['neplan_postgreSQL:viewAllElements'],
      outputFormat: 'application/json',
      filter: equalToFilter('name', nameElect)
    });
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/neplan_postgreSQL/wfs', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest2)
    }).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
      const features = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(json);
      elemetElec['name'] = features[0].values_.name;
      elemetElec['coordX'] = features[0].values_.geometry.flatCoordinates[0];
      elemetElec['coordY'] = features[0].values_.geometry.flatCoordinates[1];
      elemetElec['coords'] = features[0].values_.geometry.flatCoordinates;
    });
    return elemetElec;
  }
  elementElectrico = getName(name);
  return elementElectrico;
  }
```

y lo consumo en mi componente así:

```
cargarDatosByName(name: String): any[] {
  let lista: Array<any> = [];
  lista = this._service.listById(name);
  console.log(lista);
  return lista;
}
```

al imprimirlo en consola lo obtengo así:

[image: resultado]

```
 `[]
    coordX: -104.39924848
    coordY: 29.54486549
    coords: (2) [-104.39924848, 29.54486549]
    name: "2999"
    length: 0
      __proto__: Array(0)`
```

como accedo a sus propiedades, lo he intentado:

1. `console.log(lista[0].coordX);`
2. `console.log(lista[0]);`
3. `console.log(lista.coordX);`

y no me deja acceder a las propiedades

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. ¿Si quitas esta definición inicial: `let lista: Array<any> = [];` pasando a definir el elemento así: `let   lista = this._service.listById(name);` qué se muestra en consola?

Comment: Este código es de angularjs? Yo no veo nada que haga referencia a él en tu código

Comment: @A. Cedano Al definirlo de esa manera, da el mismo resultado.

Comment: Ya, si estás usando `angular` entonces cedo el paso a alguien más que te podrá dar recomendaciones más precisas.

Comment: Me confirmas por favor si utilizas angular o angular js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás creando un array de manera *sincrónica* y le estás asignando propiedades de manera *asincrónica* y por último accediendo a su valor de manera *sincrónica*. Eso te crea un `race condition` ya que como un arreglo es un objeto también asignarle propiedades no cambia la referencia original.

En su lugar debes intentar obtener el valor de manera asincrónica y luego manipular datos de manera sincrónica. Para eso retorna la promesa que crea el `fetch` en tu método `listById` y manipula el objeto o arreglo luego que las peticiones http terminen de ejecutarse. Yo cree un objeto porque no le vi caso a hacer un arreglo con el código de ejemplo que pusiste pero usar un arreglo con un objeto dentro es perfectamente posible.

```js
listById(name: String): any[] {
  let elementElectrico: Array < any > ;

  function getName(nameElect) {
    const elemetElec = [];
    const featureRequest2 = new WFS().writeGetFeature({
      srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureTypes: ['neplan_postgreSQL:viewAllElements'],
      outputFormat: 'application/json',
      filter: equalToFilter('name', nameElect)
    });
    return fetch('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/neplan_postgreSQL/wfs', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest2)
    }).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
      const features = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(json);
      return {
        name: features[0].values_.name,
        coordX: features[0].values_.geometry.flatCoordinates[0],
        coordY: features[0].values_.geometry.flatCoordinates[1],
        coords: features[0].values_.geometry.flatCoordinates
      };
    });
  }

  return getName(name);
}
```

Luego cuando quieras consumirlo

```
cargarDatosByName(name: String): any {
    let lista: Object = {};
    return this._service.listById(name).then(lista => {
        console.log(lista);
        return lista;
    });
}
```

Recuerda que, una vez que comiences trabajo asincrónico debes retornar promesas para que el trabajo que esté en curso pueda terminarse.

Comment: Gracias. Me salvaste, si me permite extraer la información.

Comment: @BryantCancino No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Debes devolver un objeto, no un vector. Esto es angular si mal no estoy, no angularjs, el tag lo tienes mal.

En la variable `elemetElec`, lo creas como array, pero asignas los valores como un objeto, a mi parecer el error radica ahí.

Intenta lo siguiente

```
  listById (name: String): any {
    let elementElectrico: Array<any> = [];
    function getName(nameElect) {
    let elemetElec:object = {};
    const featureRequest2 = new WFS().writeGetFeature({
      srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureTypes: ['neplan_postgreSQL:viewAllElements'],
      outputFormat: 'application/json',
      filter: equalToFilter('name', nameElect)
    });
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/neplan_postgreSQL/wfs', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest2)
    }).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
      const features = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(json);
      elemetElec['name'] = features[0].values_.name;
      elemetElec['coordX'] = features[0].values_.geometry.flatCoordinates[0];
      elemetElec['coordY'] = features[0].values_.geometry.flatCoordinates[1];
      elemetElec['coords'] = features[0].values_.geometry.flatCoordinates;
    });
    return elemetElec;
  }
  elementElectrico = getName(name);
  return elementElectrico;
  }
```

Tu componenete

```
cargarDatosByName(name: String): any {
  let lista: Object = {};
  lista = this._service.listById(name);
  console.log(lista);
  return lista;
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.
Cualquier duda me cuentas. ;)